# ComplexPloting Table with solutions

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, table

I am working with plotting roots of equation in wolfram mathematica.

```
solutions = Table[FindRoot[{Exp[z] - r}, {{z, i + j I}}], {i, 10}, {j, 10}]
```

returnes `{{{z -> 0.999389 + 0.999487 I}, {z -> 1.3 + 3.1 I}, {z ->  1.09325 + 2.92484 I}, {z -> 0.79817 + 3.33601 I}, {z ->  0.929589 + 5.02139 I}, {z -> 1.15404 + 5.28264 I},`
etc

r is PadeAproximation to Exp

My question is - how can i plot this Table using ComplexPlot? I see 2 options: removing z-> in Table( no idea how) or some specif options in ComplexListPlot. Whats the best option?

```
ComplexListPlot[solutions]
```

returnes `ComplexListPlot::ldata: {{{z->0.999389 +0.999487 I},{z->1.3 +3.1 I},<<7>>,{z->0.840192 +5.02774 I}},<<8>>,{{z->8.79142 +<<19>> I},<<8>>,{z-><<1>>}}} is not a valid dataset or list of datasets.`

Comment: Try replacing `FindRoot[...]` with `FindRoot[...][[1, 2]]`.

Answer (score 1):

As your code does not work, I take your result:

```
sol= {{{z -> 0.999389 + 0.999487 I}, {z -> 1.3 + 3.1 I}, {z ->  1.09325 + 2.92484 I}, {z -> 0.79817 + 3.33601 I}, {z ->  0.929589 + 5.02139 I}, {z -> 1.15404 + 5.28264 I}}};
```

These are replacement rules for z. To get the values:

```
res = z /. sol[[1]]
```

These are complex numbers. To plot these, you need ComplexListPlot:

```
ComplexListPlot[res, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

(*unfortunately, the image upload is not working*)

Comment: Thanks a lot! ReplaceAll (/.) helped.

Answer (score 1):

Or `NSolveValues`.

```
Clear[r, sol];
r = PadeApproximant[Exp[z], {z, 0, 4}];
sol = NSolveValues[
   Exp[z] == r && 0 <= Re[z] <= 10 && 0 <= Im[z] <= 10, z];
ComplexListPlot[sol]
```